# How do I add flags to cmake when using Google Tests on Clion?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am using Clion IDE and I have a program that compiles when not using the Google Test Sweet.  However when I try to use Google_Tests_run it gives me the error `` undefined reference to `__imp___gmpz_init' ``

Everything tells me the answer is I need to add `-lgmp` to the build command but I can't seem to find a way to do it. I thought that was what I was doing with [`set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-lgmp")`](https://github.com/mctrivia/test_gtest/blob/master/tests/CMakeLists.txt#L8)  but aparently that is not the case because the build messages say

```
C:\Users\squar\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion2021.3\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe --build /cygdrive/c/Users/squar/CLionProjects/test/build/debug --target Google_Tests_run
```

The CMakeLists.txt in my test folder is

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)
project(Google_tests)
add_subdirectory(lib)
include_directories(${gtest_SOURCE_DIR}/include ${gtest_SOURCE_DIR})

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/modules)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-lgmp")

find_package(GMP REQUIRED)
add_executable(Google_Tests_run TestClassTests.cpp)
target_link_libraries(Google_Tests_run gmp gmpxx)
target_link_libraries(Google_Tests_run test_lib)
target_link_libraries(Google_Tests_run gtest gtest_main)
```

Entire compilable code(if you don't use tests) is here https://github.com/mctrivia/test_gtest

Comment: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html

Comment: I used that here. 
 https://github.com/mctrivia/test_gtest/blob/master/tests/CMakeLists.txt#L12

Comment: Swap the first two `target_link_libraries` or use the single `target_link_libraries(Google_Tests_run test_lib ${GMP_LIBRARIES} gtest gtest_main)`

Comment: thank you.  I did not know the order mattered and you would think you would want gmp first since it is needed for the test code but swapping the order so gmp is second fixes.